# AWS CLI describes instances of particular cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have a cloudformation stack creates multiple EC2.  Is there a CLI command that describes instances of a particular cloudformation stack?

Comment: A CloudFormation stack might be responsible for launching particular Amazon EC2 instances. In doing so, your stack _might_ have added tags to the EC2 instances. You can check by selecting an EC2 instance in the EC2 management console and viewing the tags. If there are no suitable tags that identify the instances as being launched by CloudFormation, then you could modify your CloudFormation template to apply such tags in future.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to get the instance IDs that were deployed as part of a CloudFormation deployment:

```bash
$ STACK_NAME=myteststack
$ aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name "$STACK_NAME" --query 'StackResources[?ResourceType==`AWS::EC2::Instance`].PhysicalResourceId' --output text
i-0033781a7765d0b05     i-0963426e25b95e1e3
```

And you can then feed that to `describe-instances`:

```bash
$ aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name "$STACK_NAME" --query 'StackResources[?ResourceType==`AWS::EC2::Instance`].PhysicalResourceId' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | xargs -I {} aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id {}
...
```

Comment: I don't see "AWS::EC2::Instance" from the output

`aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name "$STACK_NAME" | grep  EC2
            "ResourceType": "AWS::EC2::Volume",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::EC2::Volume",`

Btw, the instances are launched by auto scaling group. Does it make any different?

Comment: @CJChang Yes, that makes it different